# Can I reference an empty web application from an mvc application in the same solution?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

If I create a blank solution, add an MVC 3 project then add an empty web application to the same solution, add a reference to the empty web application project in the MVC 3 application, how can I access the classes from the empty web application. (if there were any)

Inside of my MVC project, intellisense doesnt seem to pick up on the empty web application.

Of course, I guess the question would be, "Why would you want to reference an empty web application?" However, I would be under the assumption that I could do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you create a reference to the second project, the empty web application, you'll be able to access anything inside of that project in theory*.

You would need to either using the `using` keyword to bring the objects into scope or you'll need to call them by their fully qualified names, such as `Foo.Bar.FooBar`.

That being said, the application project will need classes in it to be accessed. If you have a completely empty project there wouldn't be anything to access in the other project.

- You won't be able to access things that depend on ASP.NET in a non-ASP.NET hosting setup, such as `HTTPContext.Current` unless your app is running on ASP.NET.